# How to execute PowerShell script on a remote PC in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

The following code executes without any errors, but there are no results returned. But when I execute it manually in PowerShell console, I get expected results.

```
var ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
var mySpace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
mySpace.Open();
ps.Runspace = mySpace;

using (var sa = new Impersonation("user", "pwd"))
{
    try
    {
        sa.Impersonate();

        ps.AddScript("Get-NetAdapter -CimSession REMOTE_PC");
        var result = ps.Invoke(); // empty data
    }
    finally
    {
        sa.UndoImpersonation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To execute commands on a remote computer powershell have a specifics commands, you can try to follow this guide (https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) and check if the solution work for you